# Best way to repeat an observable every minute rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2, repeat

I have the following method:

```
public class ParentalControlInteractor {
   public Single<Boolean> isPinSet() {
       return bamSdk.getPinManager().isPINSet();
   }
}
```

I want to call this function to run once, then repeat every minute until infinity but this seems clumsy:

```
    parentalControlInteractor.isPinSet()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .repeat(10000)
            .timeout(1600,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                Timber.e(throwable,"Error getting if Pin is set");
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            })
            .subscribe(isPinSet -> {
                this.isPinSet = isPinSet;
                Timber.d("Pin is set = " + isPinSet.toString());
                });
```

Isn't there a better way to do it? I'm using RxJava2. Also, the method above only calls it 10000 times.  I want to call it forever, like using Handler.postDelayed().

Comment: just call `repeat()` pass no parameter to it to repeat forever

Comment: I don't want it to keep calling this every second, I'd like there to be an interval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this is doing the job:

```
parentalControlInteractor.isPinSet()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .delay(10000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .repeat()
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                Timber.e(throwable,"Error getting if Pin is set");
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            })
            .subscribe(isPinSet -> {
                this.isPinSet = isPinSet;
                Timber.d("Pin is set = " + isPinSet.toString());
                });
```

Comment: does this run the first time right away or will delay also the first time?

Comment: I believe it delays the first time.

Comment: How to stop the process ?

Comment: this will just delay the result 10 seconds, it will not repeat, please check my answer

Answer (score 16):

you can use `interval()` oberator here is the code

```
DisposableObserver<Boolean> disposable = 
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .flatMap(aLong -> isPinSet().toObservable())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeWith({isPinSet -> doSomething()}, {throwable -> handleError()}, {});
```

if you want to finish this operation at any time call `disposable.dispose()`

Answer (score 8):

Try
`.repeatWhen(objectFlowable -> Flowable.timer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).repeat())`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
parentalControlInteractor.isPinSet()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .repeatWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Void>, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Void> observable) {
                return observable.delay(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        })
        .doOnError(throwable -> {
            Timber.e(throwable,"Error getting if Pin is set");
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        })
        .subscribe(isPinSet -> {
            this.isPinSet = isPinSet;
            Timber.d("Pin is set = " + isPinSet.toString());
        });
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception.

Comment: I'm not sure what exception @KristyWelsh is referring to, but this approach seems to work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Best way to repeat request every time with specific delay of first emission

```
 return Observable.interval(FIRST_ITEM_DELAY, CYCLE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                       .flatMap(aLong -> repository.repeatedRequest());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine some RxJava operators:

```
Observable.wrap(parentalControlInteractor.isPinSet().delay(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES)).repeat();
```

I found this solution very elegant and very simple