# RxJava 2 how to do something immediately and repeat every X minutes

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I know the `delay()` and `repeat()` operator and have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376253/best-way-to-repeat-an-observable-every-minute-rxjava?rq=1).

However, I want the first event to be fired immediately, not wait for X minutes.
It would be weird when user clicks a button and have to wait for X minutes to see the results right?

I want to do something like `doSomeTask().nowAndEveryXMinAfter()`.

doSomeTask:

```
Observable<Integer> doSomeTask() {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `repeatWhen` example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45376738/61158

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) operator:

```
Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Where you can specify the initial delay, and then emit every x minutes. I'm not sure what exactly you want to do, but you can for example concat this after your action if that's an observable.